# Exchanging a Canadian driving license for a UK one

Tags: driving-license, driving

I'm a British citizen who has recently returned to the UK after living in Canada for 3 years. I understand I need to fill out a D1 form to exchange my Canadian license back to a UK one (I passed my driving test in the UK), but I don't know how to answer these questions in section 2 -

**"Previous details - if your name and/or address has changed from that shown on your last license you MUST give the previous details below"**

Is this referring to my last *UK* license, or is my last license the Canadian one?

**"What date did you come to live in the UK?"**

Is this the date I was born in the UK, or the date I most recently returned?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Logically, the answer to Q2 must be the date you became a UK resident again.

Comment: Similarly, the answer to Q1 must be the last UK licence, as they only have access to UK licence information